# Returning unknown data type

Tags: c#, generics, generic-programming

This is what is happening.  I have a method called "Load" that takes a Hashtable of various parameters and returns an object serialized on disk.

```
public static T Load<T>(Hashtable settings){}
```

When calling load the user passes the settings hashtable and the type of data they want.  This is how I am trying to call it:

```
var data =DGSave.DGSave.Load<Type.GetType(type.ToString())>(h);
```

But it keeps throwing this error:

> Error CS0019: Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'System.Type' (CS0019)

My question is how can I pass the type of data I am retrieving using a variable (in this example it is "type").

Sorry if my explanation was not clear, I suck at explaining things.

Comment: You should know the type at compile time. If not you'll have to use reflection

Comment: Is there any online reference you can point me to?  I'm am looking through the chapter on reflection in "C# 5.0 In a nutshell" but can't find anything that relates to my situation.

Comment: The compiler is interpreting the brackets as the less-than and greater-then operators, causing the compiler error. You have to pass the type as a parameter to the method instead.

Comment: Why not..? [This will help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method)

Comment: Thanks, I just found the page on that, but the link you posted is a little easier to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle id with reflection

```
var type = typeof(DGSave.DGSave);
var method = type.GetMethod("Load", BindingFlags.Static).MakeGenericMethod(typeof(string));
method.Invoke(null, new object[] {h});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's almost exactly what I did right before you posted :p